# Restrict access to Mark Complete in Microsoft CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015

Dears,
We have Agents use Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015  i need some of them can mark complete the Activity and edit in any Activity, and the remain can edit in any activity but cant change the Activity status or use mark complete button. 
Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Not possible out of the box. Best way to handle this particular scenario is to prevent `Mark as Complete` using javascript based on user security role. Also never a good idea to alter out of the box buttons and their functionality.

```
function onSave(executionContext) {
    var saveMode = executionContext.getEventArgs().getSaveMode();
    if (saveMode === 58) { //mark as complete
        var canMarkAsComplete = false;
        window.Xrm.Page.context.getUserRoles().forEach(function(role) {
            if (role === 'GUID of the security role allowed to mark as complete') {
                canMarkAsComplete = true;
                return;
            }
        });
        if (!canMarkAsComplete) {
            executionContext.getEventArgs().preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks dear, but how i can check if the user can mark as complete or not

Comment: That is a business requirement, maybe users with just a particular role? or maybe create a new security role for all the users who can perform the action.

Comment: Ok assume that i need to restrict access to Agents with xyz role and give access only to Agents with CSR role, so what i should write in your code.

Comment: updated the answer, replace 'GUID of the security role..' with the actual security role guid.

Comment: Ok i will tested and i will confirm then to u, but just for confirmation this GUID i should search on it inside CRM database tables it self or i can just write the name of this role between the ' '

Comment: if you aren't familiar with form scripting, getting the guid from the database will work. The equality comparer expects a guid, not a name.